# output of MLP is always 0

Tags: nlp, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm doing matching sentence using CNN, the main algorithm is described as bellow(detailed algorithm is [here](http://www.hangli-hl.com/uploads/3/1/6/8/3168008/hu-etal-nips2014.pdf)):

1. get m words from sentence A, also get m words from sentence B. Then combine them, thus get a matrix M1 whose shape is 2m*word_embedding_dim. Next, do a convolution to the matrix we get, thus get a single value.
2. repeat step 1 until we get all the compositions of words from sentence A and B. At the same time,composite all the single value we get by convolution to form a new matrix M2.
3. Treat M2 as an image, do next: M2->conv_1->pool_1->conv_2->pool_2->fully_connect->MLP_1->single value(similarity, value in [0,1])

The code is [here](https://github.com/GaigeLynch/text_similarity_cnn)

In my training set, the labels is 0(not similar) or 1(similar), However, the output is always '0'. I have no idea where is wrong. This problem is making me mad. Is the network is too deep? Or, is the network is somewhere wrong. Could please someone help me? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: maybe you initialized your started parameters as all zeros?

Comment: I didn't them as all zeros, you can see the code as bellow: `w_conv1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([slide_window_size, slide_window_size, 1, 32], stddev=0.1),name="w_conv1")`, and `b_conv1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[32]), name="b_conv1")`

Comment: are all your activations zeros at some point? What about inputs?

Comment: Would please have a look at my [code](https://gist.github.com/GaigeLynch/3f75f9e4fbad66a285c6f491f1f22f43#file-mlp_text_cnn-py-L55) (you can see from line 55, the code above is about the pre-process of compositing 2 sentences)to see if there is something wrong? Actually, there are a lot of '0' in the inputs, the inputs is like `[197, 88, 41, 3823, 7, 70199, 46, 7, 0, 25, 7, 224937, 22619, 0, 188, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`(total 45 numbers),  Is it the inputs that make matters?